# Isolating client-side view from the server-side controller/model using DWR

Tags: jakarta-ee, client-server, dwr

I had a look at [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html)  for hosting remote client server communication. Is there a mechanism where I can connect an html file (physically present at an external client machine) to a POJO present (physically) at the server side?
My intention is to let external clients change the view but give them access to the classes defined in dwr.xml.
please let me know if my intentions are not clearly put up.

Comment: I'm not fully understand your question. The part that a client access a POJO from the server (by javascript) is the thing why use DWR. But what view do you wanna change?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Michel, for your response. 
Okay, I did some research and found [DWR Cross domain support](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/browser/xdomain.html) is the most apt for my requirement. I wanted a mechanism where I could give an option to my customer to have their own view but still use the control logic placed in my server.